# MySQL query in php only runs for 300 lines of the database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to search a database of about 5000 rows and 5 columns to get a specific number from just one. Every row is unique, meaning that no row contains the same series of variables (var1, 2, 3, 4) that equate to a unique result (in column 5).

```
$sql = "SELECT result FROM data WHERE var1 = '$var1' AND var2 = '$var2' AND var3 = '$var3' AND var4 = '$var4' LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$final = $row1[0];
```

It works perfectly for the first 300 lines, but after that it doesn't seem to run.